Different types of sentence structures
I have seen this thread today where some natives claim this is a valid sentence

By the time the police had arrived, the two men had disappeared.

Could you comment on that because I'm confused. I have never seen past perfect in two clauses that follow each other. before. https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/by-the-time-past-perfect.2505147/

There are many timeline programs for English on the net. That would probably help  you. Here's a good one: https://tonyeosenglish.weebly.com/verb-tense-timelines.html

The sentence isn't wrong, but  the first use of the past perfect is unnecessary (as the first answer on Wordreference says).

@KateBunting It really depends on context. I don't understand why you don't accept that.

Use of past perfect in two clauses.
Yes, the sentence is valid but requires context:
Detective: What happened when the police arrived at 10:00 am?
Witness: No, the police had arrived by 9:00 and the two men had disappeared.
So, I worked it around a bit but bear this in mind: The simple past action that is either express or implied does not have to be in the sentences or sentences uttered by a speaker. It is the simple past that anchors the past perfect and makes it relevant.
There is a specific usage in speech. BEFORE the police arrived the men had vanished. That's the reason for using it.

let's say there is no "special" context. I just wanna say that I did one thing before another. Then is it wrong or just redundant? 1. I ran before I took  a shower 2. I had run before I took a shower 3. I ran before I had taken a shower 4 I had run before I had taken a shower. So 1 ,2 and 3  are valid and 4 would only fine in a specific context?

@marta Please listen to what I'm saying. Unless something happens before something else, there is no reason to use the past perfect. It always precedes something else. Your examples there are fine but not like your question at all. You are merely changing your question in comments. It is you as speaker that decides the timeframe. Not us. Yes, 4 is like your question and would require context from that speaker or another speaker in another sentence.

So in my original sentence  first we used perfect to show something happened before 10 and another perfect to show they escaped before 9, yes?

The police arriving and the men disappearing had to have happened BEFORE some other thing in the simple past, like I showed in my answer. You don't need time necessarily. You need an action in the simple past. I had left when he arrived.

okay thank you  for your help

In your example, you can use either the simple past or the perfect form:

By the time the police had arrived, the two men had disappeared.
By the time the police arrived, the two men had disappeared.

Many American English speakers favor the latter, and both are acceptable. The perfect form is not unusual at all. It's often accompanied by the word "already," which emphasizes the fact that one event occurred before the other. Here are a couple of examples:

By the time I had eaten dinner, she had already done all the chores on her list.
By the time Margaret had read one book, Charles had read three.


At least leave a comment and say why you downvoted my answer!

I didn't dv it but I'd say that the PP requires context. The thing about AmE favoring the latter is not necessarily true at all.

@swmcdonnell I don't think your answer deserves a down vote, so +1. The dvs don't have any meaning - It simply means the downvoter doesn't know grammar or is following another rule (sometimes his own)

I. Before (by the time) + had indicates an unfinished or interrupted action:
OP's sentence with two "had":

"By the time the police had arrived, the two men had disappeared."

The first clause with "by the time + had" shows an incomplete action when the second action took place. It shows that "had the police arrived earlier, the two men would have been arrested." The use of "had" highlights that the opportunity to arrest the men had already passed.
This construction aligns with before + past perfect, which shows that an action was incomplete or unfulfilled when another action in the past occurred. It stresses that, when the second action happened, the first action was still in progress or had not yet been accomplished.
Reference (British Council):

We can also use before + past perfect to show that an action was not done or was incomplete when the past simple action happened:

"They left before I'd spoken to them.".
Sadly, the author died before he'd finished the series.".
.
Past perfect after before


